# Git tag on master branch pointing to merge commit -- not available from develop branch

Tags: git

I'm pretty new to gitflow: I've merged my develop branch into my master branch and created a tag, but the tag is pointing to the merge commit so `origin/master` is one commit ahead of `origin/develop`.

I have a jenkins job pulling down the develop branch and `git describe` gets the previous available tag instead of the new one.

I'd like `origin/develop` and `origin/master` to be at the same place after merging from develop into master, or at least the tag to be available from both branches. Should I create the tag on develop before merging, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

After a merge to `master`, `master` will indeed be be one commit ahead of `develop`, and it is impossible for them to both be at the same place (due to the merge itself being considered a commit). Despite `master` being one commit ahead, both branches will contain identical code.

Tagging should be done against **`master`**; the tag should be indicative of the last *version* or *release*. Ideally it would be made against a **`release`** branch, though in the absence of one, `master` is the more suitable option (as it is meant to indicate a 'stable' point in time).

It is worth mentioning, however, that you can [create a tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) retroactively if need be with:

```
$ git tag -a {tag} {commit}
```

Comment: Important note : "impossible for them to be both at the same place" is only true *just after* ther merge, and only if it is not a fast-forward merge. And even then, you're just a merge "back" master>dev away from them pointing to the exact same commit.